# How can I achieve the correct garden tap orientation when threading it in?

Tags: plumbing

I'm installing an external tap using a wall plate like this one:

[image: plate]

And a tap like this one:

[image: tap]

This might be a stupid question, but if I screw the tap into the wall plate it will end up at a certain angle. I can install the wall plate with that angle and the tap will end up with the correct orientation (i.e. pointing down). But what if I want to put another tap in later that has its thread cut slightly differently? How do I prevent it ending up upside-down or whatever? Are all the threads cut *exactly* the same in these taps?

This seems like a stupid design.

Comment: It may be the universe trying to tell you to use a [sillcock](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Prier-Products-1-2-in-x-10-in-Brass-MPT-x-S-Half-Turn-Frost-Free-Anti-Siphon-Outdoor-Faucet-Sillcock-478-10/204516668) instead of a valve, for anti-freeze protection.

Comment: Yeah or not because this solution has exactly the same anti-freeze properties. Also that pipe isn't long enough to go through my wall. I think it would only work in American houses.

Comment: Sillcocks come in a variety of lengths, so that's not a problem... and the point of a sillcock is the valve proper is at the far end from the handle.  The valve stem runs the length of the pipe and the pipe is empty except when in use. So, very different anti-freeze properties.

Comment: Ah I see, that is clever. They don't seem to be available at all in the UK though. Standard solution seems to be to add a drain cock and manually drain the tap in the winter which is what I've done. Maybe we don't get cold enough winters to bother. Also I do really like the ball valve - so much quicker to operate.

Answer (score 3):

The threads are not all exactly the same. Using some Teflon tape on the threads will allow for some adjustment without leaking. Pipe threads are tapered and will seal prior to not being able to turn further. I put a few wraps on the pipe and when it starts to get stiff to turn I will leave the faucet in the proper position. (With most fittings I could go at least 1 more full turn or sometimes even 2 so it will end up in the correct position without leaking.

Comment: Hmm even with teflon tape it still seems to go from not very stiff to can't turn it any more in about 1/8th of a turn. Maybe I need more / thicker tape...

Comment: Yeah, you're probably bottoming out. Maybe your faucet doesn't have tapered threads. Try 4-6 wraps of tape, or switch to thread compound.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't appear to be tapered. Hmm.

Comment: Found [a video](https://youtu.be/Ii6TgW9ALGM?t=135) of someone replacing a tap - looks like he just uses lots of PTFE. I'll try that.

Comment: Loads of PTFE seems to do the trick.